# How can I make the status bar white with black icons: Android 11?

Tags: android, android-11

Before to make the android status bar have dark icons you would use the following code

```
// Enables Dark Status Bar Icons//
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
```

With android 11 both `systemUiVisibility` and `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR` are deprecated

How can I achieve the same result in android 11

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a lot of figuring out, but you need the `WindowInsetsController`. There are different ways to get this controller. Using `window.insetsController` or `view.windowInsetsController`. At application startup the window version seems to crash, so at startup I now do `window.decorView.windowInsetsController`.

As described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsetsController#setSystemBarsAppearance(int,%20int)) you can show or remove the light status bar like this:

```
setSystemBarsAppearance(APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS, APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS) //Show
setSystemBarsAppearance(0, APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS) //Remove
```

Comment: Thank you I have been looking forever as well

Comment: From what I found the full line is window.insetsController?.setSystemBarsAppearance()

Comment: @Jordan Yeah it's not really clear, I've been looking for a while until I found it. Yes that line would be correct, although I had some problems at application startup using that line. So I'm using this line myself: `decorView.windowInsetsController?.setSystemBarsAppearance()`

Comment: Yeah, if you use that line it needs to be wrapped in an API check for android R. That could be why. I had the same issue at first but that fixed it for me

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I was looking for clear the light status bar and now its working fine.